# WIX reinstalling a feature increases the size of installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have a couple of features in my setup. I have also enabled the Change option. i.e. A user can change what s/he want's to install or uninstall after the initial install.

When a feature is removed using this Change option it gets uninstalled. I would have expected the size of installer to be reduced but it stays the same. Now when the feature is later added using Change option the overall size of ths installer is increased.

Is there a way to control this or does it always work like this?

Note: By size of installer I mean the size, or space in bytes/KBs/MBs it occupies, which is shown in Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: Someone also had a similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976458/uninstall-and-install-grows-the-reported-size-of-the-application) but with install and uninstall.

Answer (score 2):

The size you are referring to in the *Add/Remove Programs* is calculated automatically by the MSI engine during the [File Costing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa368593.aspx) and is defined by the [EstimatedSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105) registry key.

Usually the correctness of the advertised size is a non-issue for most setup authors and users, so I wouldn't advise putting any effort on this.
However if you must fix this, check this SO post:

[Using the EstimatedSize value inside a program uninstall key to correctly display the program size in the Add/Remove Programs list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/317647/147211)